# Get the file name which contains the latest timestamp in a directory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Lets say that in a directory i have multiple files like this:

```
Test1_2021-05-17 1139.xlsx
Test1_2021-04-17 1139.xlsx
Test1_2021-03-17 1139.xlsx
Test1_2021-02-17 1139.xlsx
Test1_2021-01-17 1139.xlsx
Test2_2021-05-17 1139.xlsx
Test2_2021-04-17 1139.xlsx
Test2_2021-03-17 1139.xlsx
Test2_2021-02-17 1139.xlsx
```

How can I find the file which contains the latest timestamp and then i want to open it as a data frame.

So, eg. o want to get the file name: Test1_2021-05-17 1139.xlsx. How can i do that with python?

I tried this one but it is not getting me the file with the latest timestamp on its name:

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/*') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

Comment: And why not `Test2_2021-05-17 1139.xlsx`? It's not based on filename?

Comment: Yes, I want to open the file that starts with Test1 and has the latest timestamp, maybe I was not clear enough, sorry about that

Comment: @corralien Yes, that is why i need to open the file with the latest timestamp because i want to inspect the content of the file because the values inside are changed compared to the previous file

Comment: I'm sorry I mean: do you need to inspect the content of EACH file?

Comment: Ahaa, no, i want to inspect only the content of the file which was created the last. Thats why i need to get the file name so then i can open it as a data frame.

Comment: @user14073111 `latest_file = max(list_of_files)` should do the job instead of `latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)` Since you're compating a list of strings, but it will only work if you have the same file name structure

Comment: @Thekingis007, thanks a lot, it also works this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to filter your filenames before:

```
import pathlib
import os.path
import pandas as pd

filename = max([f for f in pathlib.Path('/path').glob('Test_*.xlsx')], 
               key=os.path.getctime)

df = pd.DataFrame(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to make it based on the filenames, you can pass a `lamdba` function to `max()`, to modifies the items properly:

```
fNames = '''.../0010/Test1_2021-05-17 1139.xlsx
.../1212/Test1_2021-04-17 1139.xlsx
.../1212/Test1_2021-03-17 1139.xlsx
.../1444/Test1_2021-02-17 1139.xlsx
.../1212/Test1_2021-01-17 1139.xlsx
.../19/Test2_2021-05-17 1139.xlsx
.../1212/Test2_2021-04-17 1139.xlsx
.../1212/Test2_2021-03-17 1139.xlsx
.../1212/Test2_2021-02-17 1139.xlsx'''.splitlines()

# use only files containing 'Test_1':
fNames = [f for f in fNames if 'test1_' in f.lower()]

# rsplit removes the directory names.
max_fName = max(
    fNames, key=lambda p: p.rsplit('/', 1)[1].split('_', 1)[1].split(' ', 1)[0]
)
print(max_fName)

#or hard coded:
max_fName = max(fNames, key=lambda p: p.rsplit('/', 1)[1][6:16])
print(max_fName)
```

Out:

```
.../0010/Test1_2021-05-17 1139.xlsx
.../0010/Test1_2021-05-17 1139.xlsx
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @maurice, also this one works